# Always the same error when drush sup (to upgrade from 6.x to 7.x) is running for a certain time

Tags: drush, upgrading

i'm hardly trying to upgrade my Drupal 6.x installation to 7.x with the help of drush.

I'm using the command drush sup @dev2 -v -d

Every thing's working fine until Major Upgrade Step 15. I try to use the choice: Automatically enable and upgrade all modules remaining in list.

But when drush updates about 3-6 modules in the list, i'm getting this error and no more modules can't be processed without showing the same error message.

```
... some other modules processed (votingapi,xmlsitemap,util, dblog_common, etc...)....
```

Then the part with the error message:

```
Upgrading Contrib Modules from Drupal 6 to Drupal 7 Step 1
```

Upgrading module: userpoints

1. Check your notes, and the UPGRADE.txt files inside each module, to see if any special upgrade instructions apply

   There is no UPGRADE.txt file in userpoints
   Drush will now do the step 'Begin upgrade of module userpoints'.

   ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

   Upgrading Contrib Modules from Drupal 6 to Drupal 7 Step 2
   Upgrading module: userpoints
2. Fully remove the old module directory inside sites/all/modules/

   Note that Drush builds the target site in a new directory; the modules directory therefore starts off empty, and there is therefore no need to delete anything. If there is for some reason an old
   module directory in place, Drush will automatically delete it when downloading the new module.

   Skipping optional step.

   ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
   Upgrading Contrib Modules from Drupal 6 to Drupal 7 Step 3
   Upgrading module: userpoints
3. Download, unpack and move the new module directory to sites/all/modules/

   ```
     Drush has a cached version of userpoints at /Users/dennis/.drush/cache/@self-d6-to-dev2-d7/project_cache/disabled/userpoints. The destination directory is /Users/dennis/Sites/dev2/sites/all/modules/userpoints

     Drush will automatically do this step now.
     Calling _drush_recursive_copy(/Users/dennis/.drush/cache/@self-d6-to-dev2-d7/project_cache/disabled/userpoints, /Users/dennis/Sites/dev2/sites/all/modules/userpoints) [1044.77 sec, 102.01 MB]      [debug]
   ```

   ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
   Upgrading Contrib Modules from Drupal 6 to Drupal 7 Step 4
   Upgrading module: userpoints
4. Enable the module

Then I've this output:

```
Drush will automatically do this step now.
Backend invoke: /usr/bin/php /usr/local/drush/drush.php --php=/usr/bin/php  --backend=2 --verbose --debug --root=/Users/dennis/Sites/dev2 --uri=default  pm-enable userpoints 2>&1 [1045.13 sec,   [command]
102.03 MB]
/usr/bin/php /usr/local/drush/drush.php --php=/usr/bin/php  --backend=2 --verbose --debug --root=/Users/dennis/Sites/dev2 --uri=default  pm-enable userpoints 2>&1 [1045.13 sec, 102.04 MB]         [notice]
Bootstrap to phase 0. [0.01 sec, 4.96 MB]                            [bootstrap]
Drush bootstrap phase : _drush_bootstrap_drush() [0.01 sec, 5.25 MB] [bootstrap]
Cache HIT cid: 5.9-commandfiles-0-beab8c3c129fe63a55d60d824a695615 [0.02 sec, 5.27 MB]                                                                                                               [debug]
Bootstrap to phase 0. [1045.34 sec, 12.42 MB]                                                                                                                                                    [bootstrap]
Bootstrap to phase 6. [1045.37 sec, 12.42 MB]                                                                                                                                                    [bootstrap]
Drush bootstrap phase : _drush_bootstrap_drupal_root() [1045.37 sec, 12.43 MB]                                                                                                                   [bootstrap]
Initialized Drupal 7.22 root directory at /Users/dennis/Sites/dev2 [1045.41 sec, 14.49 MB]                                                                                                          [notice]
Drush bootstrap phase : _drush_bootstrap_drupal_site() [1045.41 sec, 14.49 MB]                                                                                                                   [bootstrap]
Initialized Drupal site default at sites/default [1045.41 sec, 14.5 MB]                                                                                                                             [notice]
Cache HIT cid: 5.9-commandfiles-2-c32acd775c18a90c5b41d0fc9accf5ab [1045.42 sec, 14.5 MB]                                                                                                            [debug]
Drush bootstrap phase : _drush_bootstrap_drupal_configuration() [1045.42 sec, 14.5 MB]                                                                                                           [bootstrap]
Drush bootstrap phase : _drush_bootstrap_drupal_database() [1045.43 sec, 14.51 MB]                                                                                                               [bootstrap]
Successfully connected to the Drupal database. [1045.43 sec, 14.52 MB]                                                                                                                           [bootstrap]
Drush bootstrap phase : _drush_bootstrap_drupal_full() [1045.44 sec, 15.52 MB]                                                                                                                   [bootstrap]
Cache HIT cid: 5.9-commandfiles-5-efa59ca0aabb00a052dd01ef436dba54 [1045.64 sec, 41.46 MB]                                                                                                           [debug]
Drush bootstrap phase : _drush_bootstrap_drupal_login() [1045.64 sec, 41.57 MB]                                                                                                                  [bootstrap]
Successfully logged into Drupal as Gast (uid=0) [1045.65 sec, 41.76 MB]                                                                                                                          [bootstrap]
Found command: pm-enable (commandfile=pm) [1045.65 sec, 41.76 MB]                                                                                                                                [bootstrap]
Cache MISS cid: 5.9-commandfiles--a96edeebec832dfcac7c4c036542fd68 [1046.3 sec, 44.46 MB]                                                                                                            [debug]
Cache SET cid: 5.9-commandfiles--a96edeebec832dfcac7c4c036542fd68 [1046.3 sec, 44.47 MB]                                                                                                             [debug]
The following extensions will be enabled: userpoints
Do you really want to continue? (y/n): y
WD system: userpoints module enabled. [1046.76 sec, 51.18 MB]                                                                                                                                         [info]
WD actions: 3 orphaned actions (heartbeat_activity_delete_action, userpoints_action_grant_points, user_block_ip_action) exist in the actions table. Verwaiste Aktionen entfernen [1048.31 sec,        [info]
60.01 MB]
userpoints was enabled successfully. [1048.51 sec, 59.85 MB]                                                                                                                                     [ok]
Command dispatch complete [1048.51 sec, 59.79 MB]                                                                                                                                                   [notice]
 Timer  Cum (sec)  Count  Avg (msec) 
 page   3.085      1      3084.86    

Peak memory usage was 61.74 MB [1048.51 sec, 59.78 MB]                                                                                                                                              [memory]

::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
Upgrading Contrib Modules from Drupal 6 to Drupal 7 Step 5
Upgrading module: userpoints

5. Run update.php again (you should have run it once already when upgrading core) and check for any message output.

Drush will automatically do this step now.
Backend invoke: /usr/bin/php /usr/local/drush/drush.php --php=/usr/bin/php  --backend=2 --yes --verbose --debug --root=/Users/dennis/Sites/dev2 --uri=default  updatedb 2>&1 [1048.99 sec, 102.08  [command]
MB]
/usr/bin/php /usr/local/drush/drush.php --php=/usr/bin/php  --backend=2 --yes --verbose --debug --root=/Users/dennis/Sites/dev2 --uri=default  updatedb 2>&1 [1048.99 sec, 102.09 MB]               [notice]
Bootstrap to phase 0. [0.01 sec, 4.96 MB]                            [bootstrap]
Drush bootstrap phase : _drush_bootstrap_drush() [0.01 sec, 5.25 MB] [bootstrap]
Cache HIT cid: 5.9-commandfiles-0-beab8c3c129fe63a55d60d824a695615 [0.02 sec, 5.27 MB]                                                                                                               [debug]
Bootstrap to phase 0. [1049.17 sec, 12.42 MB]                                                                                                                                                    [bootstrap]
Bootstrap to phase 2. [1049.19 sec, 12.42 MB]                                                                                                                                                    [bootstrap]
Drush bootstrap phase : _drush_bootstrap_drupal_root() [1049.2 sec, 12.43 MB]                                                                                                                    [bootstrap]
Initialized Drupal 7.22 root directory at /Users/dennis/Sites/dev2 [1049.22 sec, 14.49 MB]                                                                                                          [notice]
Drush bootstrap phase : _drush_bootstrap_drupal_site() [1049.22 sec, 14.49 MB]                                                                                                                   [bootstrap]
Initialized Drupal site default at sites/default [1049.22 sec, 14.5 MB]                                                                                                                             [notice]
Cache HIT cid: 5.9-commandfiles-2-d0694fde84f442a7d33c2119cff575f2 [1049.23 sec, 14.5 MB]                                                                                                            [debug]
Found command: updatedb (commandfile=core) [1049.23 sec, 14.5 MB]                                                                                                                                [bootstrap]
Drush bootstrap phase : _drush_bootstrap_drupal_configuration() [1049.8 sec, 28.17 MB]                                                                                                           [bootstrap]
Cache HIT cid: 5.9-commandfiles-3-ff795e0864da9d3c245f6727a8655b23 [1049.81 sec, 28.18 MB]                                                                                                           [debug]
Drush bootstrap phase : _drush_bootstrap_drupal_database() [1049.81 sec, 28.18 MB]                                                                                                               [bootstrap]
Successfully connected to the Drupal database. [1049.81 sec, 28.18 MB]                                                                                                                           [bootstrap]
Drush bootstrap phase : _drush_bootstrap_drupal_full() [1049.81 sec, 28.19 MB]                                                                                                                   [bootstrap]
Cache MISS cid: 5.9-commandfiles-5-6989c0ea5e3787ed00051dc86fc1390b [1049.99 sec, 45.45 MB]                                                                                                          [debug]
Cache SET cid: 5.9-commandfiles-5-6989c0ea5e3787ed00051dc86fc1390b [1050.01 sec, 45.45 MB]                                                                                                           [debug]
The following updates are pending:

userpoints module : 
  7000 -   Update profile category setting, allow multiple categories to be displayed. 
  7001 -   Add a few indexes to speed up contrib modules that query the `points` columns.   Add index on points columns in userpoints and userpoints_txn, as well as on the two  uid columns in userpoints_txn. No need to add a uid index in userpoints, as the  compound uid_tid index is used instead when needed.   Since these indexes are added in a 6.x update as well, they need to be conditional  in this update. Otherwise users get errors, which is bad. 
  7002 -   Increase length of operation and entity_type columns. 
  7003 -   Create the {userpoints_total} table. 
  7004 -   Filling the {userpoints_total} table. 

Do you wish to run all pending updates? (y/n): y
Backend invoke: /usr/bin/php /usr/local/drush/drush.php --php=/usr/bin/php  --backend=2 --verbose --debug --yes --root=/Users/dennis/Sites/dev2 --uri=default  updatedb-batch-process 31 31 2>&1   [command]
[1051.01 sec, 48.89 MB]
/usr/bin/php /usr/local/drush/drush.php --php=/usr/bin/php  --backend=2 --verbose --debug --yes --root=/Users/dennis/Sites/dev2 --uri=default  updatedb-batch-process 31 31 2>&1 [1051.01 sec,      [notice]
48.9 MB]
Bootstrap to phase 0. [0.01 sec, 4.96 MB]                            [bootstrap]
Drush bootstrap phase : _drush_bootstrap_drush() [0.01 sec, 5.25 MB] [bootstrap]
Cache HIT cid: 5.9-commandfiles-0-beab8c3c129fe63a55d60d824a695615 [0.02 sec, 5.27 MB]                                                                                                               [debug]
Bootstrap to phase 0. [1051.19 sec, 12.42 MB]                                                                                                                                                    [bootstrap]
Bootstrap to phase 2. [1051.21 sec, 12.42 MB]                                                                                                                                                    [bootstrap]
Drush bootstrap phase : _drush_bootstrap_drupal_root() [1051.21 sec, 12.43 MB]                                                                                                                   [bootstrap]
Initialized Drupal 7.22 root directory at /Users/dennis/Sites/dev2 [1051.23 sec, 14.49 MB]                                                                                                          [notice]
Drush bootstrap phase : _drush_bootstrap_drupal_site() [1051.24 sec, 14.49 MB]                                                                                                                   [bootstrap]
Initialized Drupal site default at sites/default [1051.24 sec, 14.5 MB]                                                                                                                             [notice]
Cache HIT cid: 5.9-commandfiles-2-d0694fde84f442a7d33c2119cff575f2 [1051.25 sec, 14.5 MB]                                                                                                            [debug]
Found command: updatedb-batch-process (commandfile=core) [1051.25 sec, 14.5 MB]                                                                                                                  [bootstrap]
Drush bootstrap phase : _drush_bootstrap_drupal_configuration() [1051.76 sec, 28.17 MB]                                                                                                          [bootstrap]
Cache HIT cid: 5.9-commandfiles-3-ff795e0864da9d3c245f6727a8655b23 [1051.76 sec, 28.18 MB]                                                                                                           [debug]
PDO::__construct(): MySQL server has gone away environment.inc:517 [1051.76 sec, 28.19 MB]                                                                                                       [warning]
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2006] MySQL server has gone away [1051.76 sec, 28.23 MB]                                                                                                                        [bootstrap]
Drush was not able to start (bootstrap) the Drupal database.                                                                                                                                     [error]
Hint: This may occur when Drush is trying to:
 * bootstrap a site that has not been installed or does not have a configured database. In this case you can select another site with a working database setup by specifying the URI to use with
the --uri parameter on the command line. See `drush topic docs-aliases` for details.
 * connect the database through a socket. The socket file may be wrong or the php-cli may have no access to it in a jailed shell. See http://drupal.org/node/1428638 for details.

Drush was attempting to connect to: 
  Drupal version    : 7.22
  Site URI          : default
  Database driver   : mysql
  Database hostname : 127.0.0.1
  Database username : root
  Database name     : dev2db
  Default theme     : garland
  Administration theme: garland
  PHP configuration : /private/etc/php.ini
  Drush version     : 5.9
  Drush configuration: 
  Drush alias files : /Users/dennis/.drush/aliases.drushrc.php
  Drupal root       : /Users/dennis/Sites/dev2
  Site path         : sites/default
  Modules path      : sites/all/modules
  Themes path       : sites/all/themes
  File directory path: sites/default/files
  Temporary file directory path: /tmp
  %paths            : Array

 [1051.77 sec, 102.18 MB]
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function batch_get() in /usr/local/drush/commands/core/drupal/batch.inc on line 80
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /usr/local/drush/drush.php:0
PHP   2. drush_main() /usr/local/drush/drush.php:19
PHP   3. _drush_bootstrap_and_dispatch() /usr/local/drush/drush.php:64
PHP   4. drush_dispatch() /usr/local/drush/drush.php:95
PHP   5. call_user_func_array() /usr/local/drush/includes/command.inc:175
PHP   6. drush_command() /usr/local/drush/includes/command.inc:175
PHP   7. _drush_invoke_hooks() /usr/local/drush/includes/command.inc:208
PHP   8. call_user_func_array() /usr/local/drush/includes/command.inc:334
PHP   9. drush_core_updatedb_batch_process() /usr/local/drush/includes/command.inc:334
PHP  10. _update_batch_command() /usr/local/drush/commands/core/core.drush.inc:1107
PHP  11. drush_batch_command() /usr/local/drush/commands/core/drupal/update_7.inc:246
PHP  12. _drush_batch_command() /usr/local/drush/includes/batch.inc:93

Fatal error: Call to undefined function batch_get() in /usr/local/drush/commands/core/drupal/batch.inc on line 80

Call Stack:
    0.0007     710016   1. {main}() /usr/local/drush/drush.php:0
    0.0298    5201720   2. drush_main() /usr/local/drush/drush.php:19
    0.1111   13019960   3. _drush_bootstrap_and_dispatch() /usr/local/drush/drush.php:64
    0.1753   15203400   4. drush_dispatch() /usr/local/drush/drush.php:95
    0.2077   15213792   5. call_user_func_array() /usr/local/drush/includes/command.inc:175
    0.2077   15214408   6. drush_command() /usr/local/drush/includes/command.inc:175
    0.2079   15215232   7. _drush_invoke_hooks() /usr/local/drush/includes/command.inc:208
    0.2087   15260392   8. call_user_func_array() /usr/local/drush/includes/command.inc:334
    0.2087   15261008   9. drush_core_updatedb_batch_process() /usr/local/drush/includes/command.inc:334
    0.2128   15873488  10. _update_batch_command() /usr/local/drush/commands/core/core.drush.inc:1107
    1.1880   32966920  11. drush_batch_command() /usr/local/drush/commands/core/drupal/update_7.inc:246
    1.1904   33063392  12. _drush_batch_command() /usr/local/drush/includes/batch.inc:93

Drush command terminated abnormally due to an unrecoverable error.                                                                                                                               [error]
Error: Call to undefined function batch_get() in /usr/local/drush/commands/core/drupal/batch.inc, line 80 [1052.29 sec, 102.18 MB]
The external command could not be executed due to an application error. [1052.43 sec, 102.18 MB]                                                                                                 [error]
Finished performing updates. [1052.43 sec, 49.08 MB]                                                                                                                                             [ok]
Command dispatch complete [1052.43 sec, 49.03 MB]                                                                                                                                                   [notice]
 Timer  Cum (sec)  Count  Avg (msec) 
 page   3.138      1      3138.28    

Peak memory usage was 50.98 MB [1052.43 sec, 49.02 MB]                                                                                                                                              [memory]
updatedb failed for userpoints [1052.63 sec, 102.22 MB]                                                                                                                                          [error]

::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

Upgrading Contrib Modules from Drupal 6 to Drupal 7 Handle Update Errors
Upgrading module: userpoints

If you have errors when you run the update.php script:

Note any error messages you see. Restore your site to its previous state, using the file and database backups you created before you started the upgrade or update process. Do not attempt to do
further updates or upgrades on a site that had update problems. Consult one of the support options listed on http://drupal.org/support.
Drush cannot do this step; you must perform it manually.

What would you like to do?
 [0]  :  Cancel                        
 [1]  :  I will do this step manually.
```

You can see, it is processing the userpoints module in this case. But for example, when i directly choose to update this module, there is no error message.

Please help me with this. Every suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: I'd make sure first that mysql don't go away

Comment: Right, this is the problem, but how?

Comment: Increase wait_timeout in your my.cnf. Also see the comments here https://drupal.org/node/587250

Comment: I already set my timeout to 6000,but this didn't help. As you can see there is no more information, why mysql gone away. I also looked into the mysql general log, but there is also no error or something else, which could cause mysql to go way. Could it be that drush ignores the parameters in my.cnf, and i have to put a "db_query('SET wait_timeout = 600'); " somewhere manually? Thanx for your advice so far.

Comment: No, drush doesn't ignore .my.cnf. What version of mysql?

Comment: I use version 5.6.12.

Comment: Well, we're going offtopic I guess. In addition to `wait_timeout`, other reasons are `max_allowed_packets` and since mysql 5.5 `open_files_limit`, due to changes in the memory allocator of InnoDB. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/innodb-plugin/1.0/en/innodb-performance-use_sys_malloc.html for reference.

Answer (score 1):

Follow the advice in the error message: restore the site to its previous state. To do this, just run drush sup again, select the appropriate restore option, and then cancel drush sup.  (Don't run with --auto).

From here, you just need to get userpoints working.  You said: "When I directly choose to update this module, there is no error message."  After userpoints has updated, run drush sup again; it should continue, and allow you to upgrade your other modules.

If you can't get userpoints to upgrade, ask for help in the userpoints issue queue.  First search it and see if there are any existing issues related to the upgrade path.

Comment: No, userpoints is not the problem. Its something with the batch process itself that cause mysql to go away. As i mentioned above, i have no problem upgrading all the modules on by one. Thanx for your help.

Comment: I think that jonhattan is on to the right answer above. Given the number of times that you'll do a major upgrade, you might consider just doing it once (restarting as necessary), and then use drupal-to-drupal migration to update content until your migration is done. See: https://drupal.org/project/migrate_d2d

Comment: But can anyone please tell me, how to get more information how this error was caused, cause "MySQL server has gone away" doesn't tell me enough. Possibly i can dig deeper to get there, but how? Maybe something like "SQL : INSERT INTO ...." , or anything else.

Comment: That's never happened to me.  Maybe try asking in a mysql support board?  c.f. http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mysql